# Perfect number logic check

Tags: c

I am writing a code to print all Perfect numbers in given range.
I performed dry run for my code. But I do not get the expected output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void perfect(int,int);
int main()
{
    int start,end;

    printf("Enter range");
    scanf("%d%d",&start,&end);

    perfect(start,end);
    return 0;
}

void perfect(int s,int e)
{
    int i=0,j=0,sum=0;
    for(i=s;i<=e;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<i;j++)
        {
            if(i%j==0)  //i contains the number in range
            {
            sum=sum+j;
            }
        }

        if(sum==i)   // if sum of all factors of the number is equal to the number then its perfect number
        {
            printf("%d",i);

        }

        }

    }
```

Input: 1 10
No Output visible.
Expected Output: 6

Comment: What is the input you tried and its output?

Comment: For one thing, you need to reset `sum = 0` in each iteration.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp yea that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize `sum` to 0 before entering the outer loop, but you don't clear it when starting the inner loop.  For each number you're testing, you need to start with a sum of 0.

```
int i=0,j=0,sum=0;
for(i=s;i<=e;i++)
{
    sum = 0;
    for(j=1;j<i;j++)
    {
        ...
```